# DatePicker format is not working in windows phone but works fine in android

Tags: xamarin.forms

It's working fine with android emulator but not working in windows phone emulator.
I have tried different Date formate but it's the default format in windows phone emulator (.i.e mm/dd/yyyy)

<  DatePicker x:Name="TestDate" Format="dd/MMM/yyyy" />